# Connect to IIS server using .pfx certificate

Tags: python, iis, selenium, ssl-certificate, mechanize-python

Hi I am new to SSL and I am trying to connect to an IIS ASP.NET web server which has issued to me a unique `.pfx` certificate to verify me to the server.

Using a browser where I have installed the certificate I am able to connect the site where I have to upload a file on a daily basis.

I am trying to write a python script to do the same task. I have tried to use the [Python Mechanize library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mechanize/).

While adding certificate I converted the `.pfx` file to `.key` and `.cer PEM` file so that it could be attached to `add_client_certificate` method, but later, I found out that IIS server accepts only `.pfx` certificate and there is no way to attach a `.pfx` certificate directly to the Mechanize browser instance.

Is there a way or another library where I can do this task?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [requests library](http://www.python-requests.org/)

```
import requests
requests.get("https://your_server", cert=('client01.cer', 'client01.key'))
```